# One scene or multiple scenes for levels?

Tags: unity

In my game there are multiple levels (300 levels) You start a level by clicking on it in the level map (like the one in candy crush etc) The levels will be having the same gameplay, character and environment but the items (stored as scriptableobjects) available and the winning criteria will be different. Now I am confused about something. Is it recommended that each level should have its own scene and script?

Comment: There are very few rules that apply universally to every kind of game. Mostly it will depend on what *your* needs are for the specific game you're making. So, tell us a bit about your game and how you're approaching it, leading to this decision you're making. On the surface, it seems like not needing to manage an extra 300 scene files would be beneficial, but maybe you've identified an issue that makes it difficult for your levels to share a common scene? Tell us about that issue, and we can help you find solutions.

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah the player wins by doing something which is very different between each level
For example in level 1  you have to draw a cat. In level 2 a dog.
Just an example lol

Comment: So is your question really about scenes, or about how to manage victory conditions?  I think we have some existing Q&A about that, which might be useful to search through for ideas.

Comment: It is not about managing victory conditions. Just whether i should  use multi scenes or single scene

Comment: If you are procedurally generating each level(like the ones in cc ect..) Once you click the level on the map the ui animates or fades out and the gameplay level fades in and generates in a single scene. Really depends on if you generate the level or have hand made preset levels.

Comment: @JustinMarkwell Yes hand made preset levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually using only one scene for multiple levels is (almost) never a good choice, unless the game is VERY small(or if you want to generate the levels procedurally) If you are planning to do multiple levels in your game, i would go for a multi-scene approach, to have a better, more organised workflow. At the end of the day it really depends on the type of game you are making.

Comment: Would that increase the size of apk if I use many scenes?

Comment: Yes but only if you use really many, many scenes. It is not going to increment the size of the apk too much. Again, it is raccomended to use multiple scenes, for the levels in your game. The final size of the apk also depends on the "size" of the scenes themselves. If a scene just contains a cube it is going to weigh a lot less than one which contains 300 cubes

Comment: I am also worried about lighting. Can I just use the same lighting for all the scenes?

Comment: Yes of course you can, you have to make sure to rebake the lighting when you load the scene. It should be done automatically by unity under Window->lighting though.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, you can use the same lighting setup for multiple levels within the same scene in Unity. Unity's lighting system is designed to work across different parts of a scene, so you can create consistent lighting across various levels without any issues. This can be especially beneficial if you want to maintain a consistent visual style and mood throughout your game.

Here's how you can ensure consistent lighting across different levels within the same scene:

1. **Setup Lighting:**
   Configure your lighting setup using Unity's lighting tools. This includes setting up directional lights, ambient lighting, reflection probes, and any other lighting components you want to use.
2. **Lighting Layers:**
   Unity's lighting system works on a per-layer basis. You can assign different GameObjects to specific lighting layers to control how they interact with the lighting. For example, you might have one layer for dynamic objects and another for static level geometry.
3. **Reuse Lighting Setup:**
   Ensure that your lighting setup is consistent across the different levels within the same scene. You can achieve this by reusing the same lighting GameObjects, settings, and lighting components.
4. **Optimize Lighting Baking:**
   If you're using baked lighting (which is common for scenes with static elements), make sure to bake your lighting after you finalize your level designs. Baked lighting can significantly improve performance and create consistent lighting across levels.
5. **Manage Scene Hierarchy:**
   Organize your scene hierarchy efficiently. You can create separate hierarchies for each level within the same scene and enable/disable them based on the level progression.
6. **Lighting Quality Settings:**
   Unity's Quality Settings allow you to control how detailed your lighting calculations are. Ensure that your lighting quality settings match the level of detail you want for your game.

By following these steps, you can use the same lighting setup to achieve consistent lighting across different levels within the same scene. This approach can save memory, reduce loading times, and help maintain a cohesive visual experience throughout your game.

Comment: This answer is barely relevant to the question at hand. It contains a ton of superfluous and superficial information nobdy asked for. Please don't post ChatGPT answers on Stack Exchange. Or anywhere else on the Internet, for that matter. When someone wants to read a LLM-generated answer, they can ask ChatGPT themselves.

Comment: The question did not ask about lighting at all.